# Excel VBA Repeated Find and Replace /from a Table/

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm trying to build a macro in Excel using `VBA` – it should convert a slew of rows of strings like `“YU-RN-PE-LT-JW-MN”` into other things `“L3,N6,W2,P9,V7,F2”`  (the dashes also ought to become commas) according to an arbitrary table specifying `“YU”` in one column, `“L3”` in another and so on.

It's the table thing that complicates normal search and find, and the repeated looking that makes normal Vlookup inadequade.

Would appreciate any help. Also please note that I've never used VBA before trying to build this macro, so assume I don't know anything.

Comment: To clarify, there will be several rows, and every row will contain a string with multiple substition candidates? Are there several columns, or just one column with several rows?

Comment: Sample data might be helpful.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usually we try something then we ask questions here but I am going to give you a hint: create a module and inside the module, and a function that will do what you want. then create your macro that run the code in the function

Comment: the correct way is that Coding Enthusiast wrote. assumed to have 2 columns and replace from item col1 to item col2. use a split(yr string,"-") to create on array with items and cicle those to create the new string

Comment: @vsoraas - correct - several rows, containing multiple sustitution candidates; only one column though

Comment: In the table where your substitutions are specified, is it safe to assume that each column only has 2 rows? Ie. say the table starts in column C. C1 will contain "YU" and C2 will contain whatever you want YU to be substituted with? Then D1 contains L3, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code that does what you're trying to accomplish.

```
Sub multi_replace()
Dim inArr, subArr, temp As Variant
Dim outArr() As String
inArr = Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value 'Replace with correct range here and below
subArr = Sheets(2).UsedRange.Value
ReDim outArr(1 To UBound(inArr, 1), 1 To UBound(inArr, 2))
For x = 1 To UBound(inArr, 1)
    For y = 1 To UBound(inArr, 2)
        temp = Split(inArr(x, y), "-")
        For i = 0 To UBound(temp)
            For j = 1 To UBound(subArr, 1)
                If temp(i) = subArr(j, 1) Then
                    temp(i) = subArr(j, 2)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j
        Next i
        outArr(x, y) = Join(temp, ",")
    Next y
Next x
With Sheets.Add
    .Range("A1").Resize(UBound(outArr, 1), UBound(outArr, 2)).Value = outArr
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! It says there is a type mismatch, however.